# Making app request android permission on launch using apktool

Tags: android, android-permissions, reverse-engineering

My app"s permissions are not being requested on launch, the only way to allow it is by `settings>apps>my_app>permissions>allow_permissions` . Its possible to make the app request it just by modifying the manifest, the activity_main.xml, or some other file in the decompiled apk folder (using apktool) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, runtime permissions must be requested in code.

They must be declared in the manifest (which they already are if they're showing up in the settings), but only the code can actually pop up the dialog to request the permission.